# jQuery setInterval delays the timer before showing it

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to make a website with 9 timers. But the timers show up after 1 second.
The code I use setInterval for each of these timers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time542').load('includes/tijd.php?article=ksm-1480-gold-extra');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time219').load('includes/tijd.php?article=dutack-spijkertacker');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time216').load('includes/tijd.php?article=buitenlamp-met-sensor');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time547').load('includes/tijd.php?article=bouwmixer-mu-1600');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time535').load('includes/tijd.php?article=doppenset-kwb-ratel');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time533').load('includes/tijd.php?article=radiator-sanicare');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time511').load('includes/tijd.php?article=werktafel-blackanddecker');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time203').load('includes/tijd.php?article=betonmolen-+-kruiwagen');}, 1000);
setInterval(function (){$('#load_time529').load('includes/tijd.php?article=wandcloset-geberit');}, 1000); 
});
```

The loadtime ID is a span where the timer is counting down.

The problem is that after loading the page it takes 1 second for all the timers to show up. Could someone enlighten me how to fix this? Or has tips on how to do this efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval does not fire at the time it is called. You should probably use anonymous named functions and use setTimeout:

```
(function tmp(){
    $('#load_time542').load('includes/tijd.php?article=ksm-1480-gold-extra');
    setTimeout(tmp,1000);
})();
(function tmp(){
    $('#load_time219').load('includes/tijd.php?article=dutack-spijkertacker');
    setTimeout(tmp,1000);
})();
etc...
```

This way the action is performed at the time you call it.